# ATmega128 microprocessor, issue regarding error when measuring distance in timer ticks?

Tags: atmega

Ok, so a laser on earth hits a mirror on the moon and bounces back. On the ATmega128 microprocessor, we use TIMER1 to capture the clock ticks when the laser shot out and the clock ticks when it returned, subtract and get a "distance" in clock ticks. (16MHz clock on ATmega128).

So we are supposed to determine how different can this measured distance be from the actual distance and what can cause it. As well as compute max error in each legal prescaler of TIMER1.

Looking at TIMER1's registers and input capture information in the ATmega128 datasheet I cannot find any kind of percentage error with the input capture. Like, this seems like a conceptual question, yet we are supposed to pull values out of the air and calculate something?

My question is if anyone knows anything of ATmega128, what values are being referred to in determining error from reading distance with timer ticks? My only guess is the error occurs when you use higher and higher prescalers because you lose preciseness when prescalers get larger. But again this is a conceptual answer and don't understand how I would calculate anything.

Comment: This is a question about microprocessor hardware design and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may try asking on Electronics.SE: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

The counters/prescalars can be assumed to be perfect and will not cause any loss of resolution.

Your original clock source will be a predominant source of errors. If you are using an external clock with a crystal, these are usually good to 50 ppm (part per million) or better.  If you are using an internal clock, the error is much higher (1% is not unreasonable for some microcontrollers).

The whole thing gets tricky if you remember your general relativity (you do have a PhD in Physics right?).  The earth's rotation and gravity come into play wrt the speed of light and distance...

Comment: Hmm, well I don't think we are worrying about any physics, just how off the measured value can be from the actual value based only on the fact that we are using clock ticks to calculate distance. See the issue is we are not told what the internal clock is. We are not given any specifics or info on anything but are apparently supposed to calculate something.... :/

Comment: You can google for the ATmega128 data sheet and read it to figure out the error of the clock, assuming it is an internal clock.